# Is wrapping an image with an anchor an issue for cross-device email templates?

Tags: html, image, email, hyperlink

I know, I should use something like [Bulletproof Email Buttons](https://buttons.cm/) service for such purposes, but I have a case, where I need to use an image wrapped with an `<a>` tag to represent a link in my email template. I ran a test with `testi.at` and it appears to be represented correctly for almost 100% of clients (up to Outlook 2007). I cannot check if such image link is 100% clickable though. My question is if there are any known issues with this approach?

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="http://example.com">
            <img src="https://some-image-src.png" width="100" height="50" alt="Sample image" />
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common practice and there is no downside that I can think of. One recommandation I'd make is to add the following styles on your image element:

- `vertical-align:middle;` This prevents a small gap to appear below images in email clients using an HTML5 doctype.
- `border:none;` This prevents a blue outline to appear on older email clients running on Internet Explorer’s rendering engine (like Outlook 2003 for example).

Also, be careful, there's a typo in your code (`scr` instead of `src`).

Comment: Thanks! This is something I was looking for :)